# Net::FTP - having trouble finding the directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp, net-ftp

I'm having trouble connecting to a hosted account via ftp and simply listing the files in a given directory.

Below is the code I have stored in a simple .rb file

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'open-uri'


Net::FTP.open('#########', '########', '#######') do |ftp|
    ftp.chdir('/webroot/irst/connect')
    files = ftp.list('n*')
    puts '#{files}'
end
```

It seems to connect to the hosted account fine but always says it can't find directory.
`getresp': 550 Can't change directory to /webroot/irst/connect: No such file or directory (Net::FTPPermError)

I do have it set up that the ftp user can only have access to this particular directory on my hosted account.  Not sure if that makes a difference or not.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you `cd /webroot/irst/connect` if you connect via the `ftp` command line client?

Comment: no it doesn't appear to work

Comment: `'/webroot/irst/connect'` has smell to it. Could it be `'/webroot/first/connect'` instead?